# Hyperbolic equations-characteristic system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Let the system:
$$\alpha(x,t,u)u_t+\beta(x,t,u)u_x=f(x,t,u)$$
To find the characteristic equations:
$$\frac{du}{ds}=\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} \frac{dt}{ds}+\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} \frac{dx}{ds}$$
$$u=u(x(s),t(s))$$

The characteristic system for first degree equation:
$$ds=\frac{dt}{\alpha(x,t,u)}=\frac{dx}{\beta(x,t,u)}=\frac{du}{f(x,t,u)}$$

We have reduced the solution of a system of PDEs to the solution of a system of ODEs.
$$$$
Could you explain me why we have found the characteristic system? Do we need this to solve hyperbolic equations?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic system shows you how the information (initial conditions) propagates through space and time. This is great for problems such as seeing how shock waves move. It is also leads to a nice way to generate numerical boundary conditions for a truncated domain (Riemann Invariants).

Comment: Ahaa..Ok!!!
$$$$
In my notes thee is an example: $$ \\ $$ 
$$v_t+\sqrt{ab} v_x=0$$
The characteristic system for this equation is:
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{ab}}=\frac{dv}{0}$$ 
But why does then the following stand??
$$v=\text{ constant, when } \frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{ab}$$??

Comment: $v$ will be a constant in that case because the equation will represent a total differential $\frac{dv}{dt}= \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$ and because $\frac{dv}{dt}=0$ then $v$ = constant.

Comment: Ahaa..Ok!! I understand!!! 
$$$$
So $\displaystyle{v=\text{ constant }, v=u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2}$, when $\displaystyle{\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{ab}}$. 
$\displaystyle{x=\sqrt{ab}t+c \Rightarrow c=x- \sqrt{ab}t}$.
$\displaystyle{v}$ is constant when $\displaystyle{x-\sqrt{ab}t}$ is constant.
That means that $$u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2=\frac{f(x-\sqrt{ab}t)}{2}$$
Could you explain me how we conclude to the last relation??

Comment: I am not certain where $u_1$ and $u_2$ and the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ come from (in this case) - but $f(x-\sqrt{ab}t)$ satisfies your original differential equation for $v$. So this shows how the initial conditions propagate along the lines $x=\sqrt{ab}t+c$

Comment: At the beginning we had set $ \displaystyle{v=u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2}$, then we got (by replacing in an other equation): $ \displaystyle{v_t+\sqrt{ab}v_x=0}$.Then we know that $v$ is conctant when $\displaystyle{\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{ab}}$, that means when $ \displaystyle{c=x-\sqrt{ab}t}$, so when $\displaystyle{x-\sqrt{ab}t}$ is constant. 
$$v: \text{ constant } \Rightarrow v=C' \Rightarrow u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2=C'$$
So do we consider that this $C'$ is equal to $\frac{f(x-\sqrt{ab}t)}{2}$? Is $\frac{f(x-\sqrt{ab}t)}{2}$ a constant, since it is the value of a function at specific number?

Comment: Yes - that is correct. The constant is equal to the the value of the initial condition at a point $x$ - and along each characteristic curve (one for each $x$) $v$ is a constant

Comment: I got stuck right now... :/ Couldn't we also let it $$u_1+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}u_2=C'$$?? Why do we have to set $$C'=\frac{f(x-\sqrt{ab}t)}{2}$$?? How did we find it??

Comment: Do we suppose that there is a function $f$ such that at the point $(x-\sqrt{ab}t)$ it's equal to $2C'$?

Comment: The main idea behind all the method of characteristics cam from d'Alemberts solution to the wave equation where $u_{tt} -c^2 u_{xx} = 0$ and $u(x,t=0) = f(x)$ and the recognition that in the case of a wave equation - we can decompose the wave field into left and right traveling waves: $u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x-ct) + f(x+ct))$ where $f(x-ct)$ is a right traveling wave and $f(x+ct)$ is a left traveling wave. The method of characteristics takes this notion to the next level by finding transformations of coordinates and dependent variables to seek these wave like answers.